# Как сделать редирект на nginx, в зависимости от части URL?

Tags: php, сервер, nginx, redirect, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте, суть задачи.
Имеем такой путь

```
site.com/seveniry-dlya-turistov/...
```

(где ... идет символьный код конкретной записи(товара), а перед ним, как можно догадаться - раздел этого товара)
Те показываем на сайте site.com в разделе "сувениры для туристов" страницу какого-то сувенира.

Мне необходимо сделать редирект такого типа:
Если идет запрос на .../seveniry-dlya-turistov/.. подменять название раздела на название .../seveniry/, те если идет запрос на

```
site.com/seveniry-dlya-turistov/elemnet1/
```

мы должны сделать 301 редирект на

```
site.com/seveniry/elemnet1/
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, и почему не работает вот так (я могу зайти по прежнему по ссылке ..souvernirs-dlya-tourists... )

```
            location ~^/catalog/souvernirs-dlya-tourists/(.*)$ {
                rewrite ^/souvernirs-dlya-tourists/(.*)$ /seveniry/$1 last;
            }
            location /catalog/souvernirs-dlya-tourists/{
                return 301 /catalog/seveniry/;
            }
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Потому что локейшену `/catalog` не соответствует урл `/catalog/bla-bla-bla`

Comment: Скорее потому что `location /catalog` не соответсвует запросу `/souvenirs-for-tourist/...`. И стоит определиться тем как вы транслитерируете «сувениры»

Comment: да, ошибся, транслитерирую  всегда одинаково конечно же.

location /souvernirs-for-tourists/ {
    rewrite ^/catalog/souvernirs-for-tourists/(.*)$ /catalog/suveniry/$1 break;
 return  301;
}

Comment: Я не вижу в адресе части `/catalog/`. Откуда он вообще появился?

Comment: я думал, это не особо важно, для постановки задачи, тк "catalog" своего рода константа, простите.

Comment: Ещё раз. У вас адрес `example.com/suveniry-dlya-turistov/` или  `example.com/catalog/suveniry-dlya-turistov/`?

Comment: У меня адрес example.com/catalog/suveniry-dlya-turistov/...
нужен редирект на
example.com/catalog/suveniry/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И `location`, и `rewrite` всегда работают с полным `$uri`, так что нельзя просто взять и пропустить часть адреса. Вот так должно работать:

```
location ^~ /catalog/souvernirs-dlya-tourists/ {
    rewrite ^/catalog/souvernirs-dlya-tourists(.*)$ /catalog/seveniry$1 permanent;
}
```

Про `^~` читать в документации http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, НО
теперь выбрасывают ошибку такой урл expample.com/catalog/handbags/ 301 Moved Permanently

те другой раздел товаров на сайте...

Comment: 301 это не ошибка. Мне надоело гадать. Создайте нормальный новый вопрос и приведите полный конфиг сервера